# How to change a custom bootstrap input onchange

Tags: javascript, html

I have this form below:

```html
<link rel="stylesheet" href="https://cdn.jsdelivr.net/npm/bootstrap@5.2.3/dist/css/bootstrap.min.css" integrity="sha384-rbsA2VBKQhggwzxH7pPCaAqO46MgnOM80zW1RWuH61DGLwZJEdK2Kadq2F9CUG65" crossorigin="anonymous">

<link rel="stylesheet" href="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/font-awesome/6.3.0/css/all.min.css" integrity="sha512-SzlrxWUlpfuzQ+pcUCosxcglQRNAq/DZjVsC0lE40xsADsfeQoEypE+enwcOiGjk/bSuGGKHEyjSoQ1zVisanQ==" crossorigin="anonymous" referrerpolicy="no-referrer" />

<form method="post">
  <div class="form-group">
    <label for="model">Offer Model / Type</label>
    <select name="model" id="model" class="form-control" required>
      <option value="1">Set Rate</option>
      <option value="2">Percentage</option>
    </select>
  </div>
  <div class="form-group">
    <label for="price">Price:</label>
    <div class="input-group">
      <div class="input-group-prepend">
        <span class="input-group-text">
                <i class="fas fa-dollar-sign"></i>
            </span>
      </div>
      <input type="text" id="price" name="price" class="form-control" required>
    </div>
  </div>
  <button type="submit">Update Product Price</button>
</form>
```

I am trying to make it so where when someone selects the percentage in the select input, it changes the price input below it, from the `$` prepending the input to a `%` sign at the end of the input and of course reverse back if they change back to set rate.

I am not completely familiar with Java Script. Can anyone please help me figure out the correct way to achieve this?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can do it using `onchange` event on the model select, then based on the selected option we show either the percentage or dollar.

If you are planning to use jquery this could be helpfull instead of the js code bellow:

```
$( "#model" ).change(function() {
    $('#percent').toggleClass('d-none');
    $('#dollar').toggleClass('d-none');
});
```

```js
document.getElementById("model").addEventListener("change", myFunction);

function myFunction() {
  var model = document.getElementById("model").value;
  var dollar = document.getElementById("dollar");
  var percent = document.getElementById("percent");
  
  if (model == 1) {
    percent.classList.add('d-none');
    dollar.classList.remove('d-none');
  } else {
    dollar.classList.add('d-none');
    percent.classList.remove('d-none');
  }
}
```

```html
<link rel="stylesheet" href="https://cdn.jsdelivr.net/npm/bootstrap@5.2.3/dist/css/bootstrap.min.css" integrity="sha384-rbsA2VBKQhggwzxH7pPCaAqO46MgnOM80zW1RWuH61DGLwZJEdK2Kadq2F9CUG65" crossorigin="anonymous">

<link rel="stylesheet" href="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/font-awesome/6.3.0/css/all.min.css" integrity="sha512-SzlrxWUlpfuzQ+pcUCosxcglQRNAq/DZjVsC0lE40xsADsfeQoEypE+enwcOiGjk/bSuGGKHEyjSoQ1zVisanQ==" crossorigin="anonymous" referrerpolicy="no-referrer" />

<form method="post">
  <div class="form-group">
    <label for="model">Offer Model / Type</label>
    <select name="model" id="model" class="form-control" required>
      <option value="1">Set Rate</option>
      <option value="2">Percentage</option>
    </select>
  </div>
  <div class="form-group">
    <label for="price">Price:</label>
    <div class="input-group">
      <div class="input-group-prepend" id="dollar">
        <span class="input-group-text">
                <i class="fas fa-dollar-sign"></i>
            </span>
      </div>
      <input type="text" id="price" name="price" class="form-control" required>
      <div class="input-group-prepend d-none" id="percent">
        <span class="input-group-text">
                <i class="fas fa-percent"></i>
            </span>
      </div>
    </div>
  </div>
  <button type="submit">Update Product Price</button>
</form>
```

Comment: There are few things I would correct: 1) jQuery wasn't a dependency that you could take for granted 2) the dropdown value is available without fetching the selected option 3) the visibility toggle could be achieved with shortest code by selecting all of them and toggling the given class. But apart from that, the issue was correctly addressed and there were not enough clues to go any further

Comment: Thanks @DiegoD for your remarks, I have applied most of them